# Instalación de kivy, ¿que salio mal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, instalacion

El día de ayer intente instalar kivy y me ha surgido un error que desconozco, cabe aclarar que seguí los pasos que dicta la pagina oficial al pie de la letra, mi versión de Python es 3.6.5
El error es

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.app'; 'kivy' is not a
>   package

Me ayudaría mucho cualquier tipo de información.

Comment: Hola santiago bienvenido a StackOverflow, antes de continuar te recomiendo revises la sección de como realizar una pregunta,es de gran utilidad que incluyas un fragmento de codigo como muestra de lo que has hecho , y en este caso una imagen o el error tal cual lo arroja tu IDE o editor de código.

Comment: Hola Santiago si la instalación fue correcta, una causa muy común de este error es que **hayas llamado a un archivo en tu directorio actual (posiblemente el mismo script donde importas `kivy.app`) como `kivy.py`**. Si tienes cualquier archivo llamado `kivy` cambia el nombre para no solapar el paquete, porque en caso contrario intenta importar este módulo. Vigila que no exista tampoco ningún archivo de bytecode llamado `kivy.pyc` en ese mismo directorio, si lo hay elimínelo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta escribir en CMD:

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url
```

https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/

Para mi funciono